# ¿Como puedo ordenar números con estas variables?

Tags: javascript

Me pueden ayudar a mostrar estas 3 variables ordenadas por favor, para este caso no puedo usar arrays

```js
let num1 = 6;
let num2 = 4;
let num3 = 7;

console.log(`Los números ordenados de mayor a menor son... nombeVariable`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes crear una función y utilizar `if` anidados para ordenarlos

Si los números fueran a, b y c entonces tendrías todas las combinaciones siguientes:

```
a,b,c
a,c,b
b,a,c
b,c,a
c,a,b
c,b,a
```

Para ordenar los valores tienes que comparar si el primer número es menor o igual al segundo y si el segundo es menor o igual al tercero para cada una de las combinaciones anteriores

Por lo tanto podrías hacer algo así:

```
let num1 = 6;
let num2 = 4;
let num3 = 7;

function ordena (a, b, c) {
    if (a <= b && b <= c)
        document.write(a, b, c);
    else if (a <= c && c <= b)
        document.write(a, c, b);
    else if (b <= a && a <= c)
        document.write(b, a, c);
    else if (b <= c && c <= a)
        document.write(b, c, a);
    else if (c <= a && a <= b)
        document.write(c, a, b);
    else
        document.write(c, b, a);
}

ordena(num1, num2, num3);
```

Comment: No me parece una buena solución anidar `else-if` para representar todas las convinaciones.  Es muy poco escalable y genera mucho codigo pudiendo hacerse mas simple

Comment: Si, es posible usar otros métodos pero es una forma fácil de entender como resolverlo